# Scss theming depends on body class with predefined variables

Tags: sass, theming

I want to have checkbox which, when you clicked it add class to body tag for example like 'dark-theme' or 'light theme'. The problem is that theming requirment is appeared after i styled all elements, and it would be suicide to change each element styles now. Please help

```
$color-white: #ffffff;
$color-black: #000000;

// Dark

$color-green: #328332;
$color-red: #a23232;

$color-background-dark: #212734;
$color-backgound-light: #31394c;

$color-text: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
$color-text-darker: #B8BCC6;
$color-text-active: #ffffff;

$color-button-primary: #0078ff;
$color-button-primary-text: #ffffff;

$color-button-secondary: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
$color-button-secondary-text: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
$color-button-secondary-active: #B8BCC6;
$color-button-secondary-text-active: #B8BCC6;

$color-line: #3d465e;
$color-line-darker: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);

$color-table-dark-row: #2C3345;


// Light

$color-green: #006400;
$color-red: #8b0000;

$color-background-dark: #f5f5f5;
$color-backgound-light: #ffffff;

$color-text: #b3b3b3;
$color-text-darker: #808080;
$color-text-active: #000000;

$color-button-primary: #0078ff;
$color-button-primary-text: #ffffff;

$color-button-secondary: #b3b3b3;
$color-button-secondary-text: #b3b3b3;
$color-button-secondary-active: #808080;
$color-button-secondary-text-active: #808080;

$color-line: #f5f5f5;
$color-line-darker: #b3b3b3;

$color-table-dark-row: #FAFAFA;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compile css files twice for each theme with different colors (and other editable things).

File with all "light" variables `light-theme.scss`:

```
$color: black;
$background: white;
```

File with all "dark" variables `dark.scss`:

```
$color: white;
$background: black;
```

File that contains all you styles `_style.scss`:

```
@import '_button.scss'; // If you are importing something
@import '_header.scss';

element{
  color: $color;
  background: $background;
}
```

And file where all themes are generated `themes.scss`:

```
.light {
  @import 'light-theme';
  @import '_styles';
}

.dark {
  @import 'dark-theme';
  @import '_styles';
}
```

Css output:

```
.dark element {
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

.light element {
  color: black;
  background: gray;
}
```