# Advanced SCSS structure: E.g. dynamic variables depending on the existence of a specific parent/outer class

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I'm trying to find out whether the following logic, that would allow for a more modular approach, can be implemented or not:

Challenge:

I got three major categories in my app: running, swimming, biking, each with their own theme/color, e.g.

scss:

```
$category-colors: (
    'running': red;
    'swimming': blue;
    'biking': green;
)
```

Throughout the app, specific components and nested components should adapt e.g. their background-color to the color of the context, meaning to the color of one of the categories. The following is one such component:

html:

```
<div class="running">
    <div class="form">
        <div class="form__header">
            <h3>New</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="form__content">
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

scss:

```
.form {
  &__header {
    height: 100px;

    // 'running' is not available here but it illustrates what I'm trying to achieve
    background: map-get($category-colors, 'running');
  }
  &__content {
    height: 50vh;
  }
}
```

The background color should be dynamically set depending on the presence of the parent/grandparent/n-parent `running`. Is there any way to get 'category' dynamically?

I could to add a suffix for the class that should adopt that theme/color like `form__header_running` but I couldn't find a way to extract "running" as a variable to then map the color.

I tried something like the following, but the variables somehow always ends up to be the last one in that chain, meaning 'biking', even if `biking` is not present on the parent.

```
.form {
  $bgColor: black !default;

  .running & {
    $bgColor: map-get($category-colors, 'running')
  }

  .swimming & {
    $bgColor: map-get($category-colors, 'swimming')
  }

  .biking & {
    $bgColor: map-get($category-colors, 'biking')
  }

  &__header {
    height: 100px;
    background: $bgColor;
  }

  &__content {
    height: 50vh;
  }

  // image much more children/sub children, so the simple use of $bgColor would be much more efficient
}
```

Any idea/concepts on how to achieve what I want?

Any inputs on a styling structure/architecture you would choose for a larger app with similar demands?

Looking forward to a discussion!

Comment: Check this answer, it worked for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53518881/scss-theming-depends-on-body-class-with-predefined-variables